# How to find files with same size?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file structure like so

```
a/file1
a/file2
a/file3
a/...
b/file1
b/file2
b/file3
b/...
...
```

where within each dir, some files have the same file size, and I would like to delete those.

I guess if the problem could be solved for one dir e.g. dir `a`, then I could wrap a for-loop around it?

```
for f in *; do
???
done
```

But how do I find files with same size?

Comment: are they Same size or identical ones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution working with "file names with spaces" (based on Kent (+1)  and awiebe (+1) posts):

```
for FILE in *; do stat -c"%s/%n" "$FILE"; done | awk -F/ '{if ($1 in a)print $2; else a[$1]=1}' | xargs echo rm
```

to make it remove duplicates, remove `echo` from xargs.

Comment: How do I modify this if I want to find files recursively within unlimited number of subdirectories? That would really help.

Answer (score 9):

```
 ls -l|grep '^-'|awk '{if(a[$5]){ a[$5]=a[$5]"\n"$NF; b[$5]++;} else a[$5]=$NF} END{for(x in b)print a[x];}'
```

this will only check files, no directories.

$5 is the size of ls command

test:

```
kent@ArchT60:/tmp/t$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent  51 Sep 24 22:23 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 153 Sep 24 22:24 all
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent  51 Sep 24 22:23 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent  51 Sep 24 22:23 c
kent@ArchT60:/tmp/t$ ls -l|grep '^-'|awk '{if(a[$5]){ a[$5]=a[$5]"\n"$NF; b[$5]++;} else a[$5]=$NF} END{for(x in b)print a[x];}'
a
b
c
kent@ArchT60:/tmp/t$
```

**update based on  Michał Šrajer 's comment**:

**Now filenames with spaces are also supported**

command:

```
 ls -l|grep '^-'|awk '{ f=""; if(NF>9)for(i=9;i<=NF;i++)f=f?f" "$i:$i; else f=$9; 
        if(a[$5]){ a[$5]=a[$5]"\n"f; b[$5]++;} else a[$5]=f}END{for(x in b)print a[x];}'
```

test:

```
kent@ArchT60:/tmp/t$ l
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent  51 Sep 24 22:23 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 153 Sep 24 22:24 all
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent  51 Sep 24 22:23 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent  51 Sep 24 22:23 c
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent  51 Sep 24 22:40 x y

kent@ArchT60:/tmp/t$ ls -l|grep '^-'|awk '{ f=""
        if(NF>9)for(i=9;i<=NF;i++)f=f?f" "$i:$i; else f=$9; 
        if(a[$5]){ a[$5]=a[$5]"\n"f; b[$5]++;} else a[$5]=f} END{for(x in b)print a[x];}'
a
b
c
x y

kent@ArchT60:/tmp/t$
```

Comment: Great solution (+1). For those not familiar with awk, the `$NF` is a last field (file name). One, remark - this solution will not work with filenames containing spaces.

Comment: Cool solution! =) If I do `for f in $(find . -type d);do cd "$f" && your_solution && cd ..;done` then the `cd` command fails. How would you execute your script in each dir?

Comment: @MichałŠrajer thanks a lot for pointing this out. I have updated my answer based on your comment. However there is still a limitation, if a filename has continuous spaces, e.g. `"foo              bar" `the awk line will fail. ^_^

Comment: @SandraSchlichting let's take an example, say you run your for script under "/tmp". Your `find . -type d `will find all dirs (sub dirs as well) under /tmp. let's say under /tmp, we have /tmp/a, /tmp/a/a2/a3, /tmp/b. your "find" output would be ./a, ./a/a2/a3 and ./b. so if you cd ./a/a2/a3 and done something, then `cd .. `will bring you to /tmp/a/a2, next you want to do cd "./b", obviously, there is no "b" dir under /tmp/a/a2. so you got it. the error has nothing to do with the awk. you have to refine your for-find script.

Comment: @Kent : I see. I should of course use `-maxdepth 1` : `for f in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d);do cd "$f" && your_solution;done`. No errors, but no output either. I suspect the `cd "$f=` doesn't really cd.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting an idea (not sure if it suits your needs) is, save your PWD to a var ($MYPWD) before you start the for loop, then change ` cd "$f" && your_solution && cd ..` to `cd "$f" && your_solution && cd "$MYPWD"`

Comment: @Kent: I have located the problem, but not a solution. The script can't get out of the dir once it have cd'ed to it. This script shows that. `PWD=$(pwd); for f in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d);do cd "$f";pwd; cd $PWD;done`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3756/discussion-between-sandra-schlichting-and-kent)

Answer (score 3):

Here is code if you need the size of a file:

```
FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")
echo "Size of $FILENAME = $FILESIZE bytes."
```

Then use a for loop to get the first item in your structure,
Store the size of that file in a variable.

Nest a for loop in that for loop to each item in your structure(excluding the current item) to the current item.

Route all the names of identical files into a text file to ensure you have written you script correctly(insteed of executing rm immediately) .

Execute rm on the contents of this file.

Answer (score 2):

Plain bash solution

```
find -not -empty -type f -printf "%s\n" | 
sort -rn | uniq -d | 
xargs -I{} -n1 find -type f -size {}c -print0 | 
xargs -0 du | sort
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the accepted answer, the following provides a list of all the files of the same size in the current directory (so you can choose which one to keep), sorted by size:

```
for FILE in *; do stat -c"%s/%n" "$FILE"; done | awk -F/ '{if ($1 in a)print a[$1]"\n"$2; else a[$1]=$2}' | sort -u | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 ls -lS
```

To determine if the files are actually the same, not just the contain the same number of bytes, do an `shasum` or `md5sum` on each file:

```
for FILE in *; do stat -c"%s/%n" "$FILE"; done | awk -F/ '{if ($1 in a)print a[$1]"\n"$2; else a[$1]=$2}' | sort -u | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n1 shasum
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like what you really want is a [duplicate file finder](http://www.supportforums.net/showthread.php?tid=15675)?

Comment: One would think so but I'm finding that large videos created by youtube-dl are not identical, but close enough to the point you want to delete one of them.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like this has been answered several times and in several different ways, so I may be beating a dead horse but here goes...

find DIR_TO_RUN_ON -size SIZE_OF_FILE_TO_MATCH -exec rm {} \;

find is an awesome command and I highly recommend reading its manpage.