# Finding files with same size (potential duplicates) in nested sub-folders in Linux Mint shell?

Tags: bash, duplicates, linux-mint

I have used `rdfind`, `fdupes` and `fslint` and have looked at previous posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541616/how-to-find-files-with-same-size) one. However the solution in the linked post does't help with files scattered in nested sub-folders. `rdfind`, `fdupes` and `fslint` work well, they removed a lot of duplicate files, but fail to find all of them. I still can see a lot of duplicate files that have exactly the same file size.
Is there any way that I can find all files that have the same file size scattered in nested sub-directories of a folder?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#prefix each filepath with the size of the file padded to 10 places
find . -type f -printf "%10s\t%p\n" | 
sort --numeric | #sort numerically (uniq needs this) 
uniq --repeated --check-chars=10 #select duplicates
```

See the respective manpages for more details.

Comment: Brilliant! I see all of the duplicates now. Kudos!

Comment: `--repeated` print only one filename per filesize. I changed to `-D` to see all duplicates.

Comment: hint: use `-links 1` arg for `find` to ignore hardlinks.

Answer (score 1):

If rdfind, fdupes and fslint didn't find them then they are not duplicates; they are just files which happen to be the same size.

Comment: They have exactly the same content, same file size to the last precision and even the same name. I am sure they differ in some other senses which caused those packages to ignore them.

Comment: Aha - all 3 of those utilities ignore files that are already hardlinked.  So for example if you create a test folder and hardlinks like this:

`$ mkdir test && cd test && echo hello > file1 && ln file1 file2`
... then you will have 2 duplicate files:
`$ md5sum file1 file2 # returns: b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184  file1
b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184  file2`
... but fdupes will ignore them:
`$ fdupes -m . # returns
No duplicates found.`
... unless you specify the --hardlinks option:
`$ fdupes --hardlinks . -->
./file1                                 
./file2`

Comment: interesting input! I will make sure to give it a shot and reply.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem (cleaning up duplicates), you may find it worth using a tool such as `rdfind`.  My Debian system says:

> Package: rdfind
>   Priority: extra
>   Section: utils
>   Description: find duplicate files utility
>
> > rdfind is a program to find duplicate files and optionally list,
> >     delete them or replace them with symlinks or hard links.  It is a 
> >     command line program written in C++, which has proven to be pretty
> >     quick compared to its alternatives.
>
> Homepage: http://rdfind.pauldreik.se/

As far as I understand, it works by checksumming candidate files.  So if your potential duplicates aren't exactly the same (e.g. object files produced from a non-repeatable build), it won't consider them duplicates.

Comment: I also used `rdfind`, sorry I forgot to mention it. I will edit to include that too. It also doesn't find any duplicate in a folder crowded with thousands of them. I guess the reason must be that they have different md5 check-sums.