# Find files with the same size and dellete all duplicates except the one has the shortest name using shell script

Tags: shell, duplicates

I have a directory containing duplicated files like below:

```
abcd.mp3 <-- keep the original  
abcd (1).mp3 <-- delete this one  
abcd (2).mp3 <-- delete this one  
abcd (1)(1).mp3 <-- delete this one
```

Currently I have this from the solution discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541616/how-to-find-files-with-same-size).

```
for FILE in *; do stat -c"%s/%n" "$FILE"; done | awk -F/ '{if ($1 in a)print $2; else a[$1]=1}' | xargs rm
```

However it doesn't wrap file names with spaces in it with a double quote so it outputs like below:

```
rm abcd.mp3 abcd (1).mp3 abcd (2).mp3 abcd (1)(1).mp3
```

So what am I missing to make it ignore the first item in the result which is the original file as well as put a double quote around the file names with spaces in it like below?

```
rm "abcd (1).mp3" "abcd (2).mp3" "abcd (1)(1).mp3"
```

Comment: There are many "finddup" commands out there.  It might be easier to use or modify one of them than to develop a new one from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for FILE in *; do stat -c"%s/%n" "$FILE"; done | awk -F/ '{if ("$1" in a) print "$2"; else a["$1"]=1}' | xargs rm
```